# Problems with: for each - in

Tags: vba, outlook

Hi im creating a macro using vba in outlook 2013, i need to save the las message (most recent) in mi inbox to an .msg archive in the hard disk. i have this code:

```
Sub prueba(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oNameSpace As NameSpace
Dim oFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim oMailItem As MailItem

Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = oNameSpace.Folders("personal folder").Folders("inbox")

For Each oMailItem In oFolder.Items
MsgBox (oMailItem.Subject)
oMailItem.SaveAs "C:\test\" & oMailItem.Subject & ".msg", olMSG

Next
End Sub
```

but my problem is with the line:

```
For Each oMailItem In oFolder.Items
```

because I want to save only the last message, I need to do something like:

```
set omailitem = ofolder.items.getlast
```

but I can't do it, I need help !

Comment: no, im not sure, i just want to assign the last item(mail) of the inbox, because i want to save as .msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort the Items collection first:

```
set Items = ofolder.items
Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", false
set Item = Items.GetLast
MsgBox Item.Subject
```

Comment: it works, but how i can do the same with:oMailItem, o i cant do that ? thanks !

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do out mean the variable name? Just use oMailItem instead of Item in the script above.

Comment: yes, just that, when i replaced in your code, the omailitem variable, but i discovered how to doit. (just replace item for oumailitem) C:

Comment: the last question, how i can export the .msg with out a confirmation of outlook, just automatical ?

Comment: MailItem.SaveAs "c:\myfile.msg", olMsg

Comment: Are u sure?, when i write:
    MailItem.SaveAs "c:\myfile.msg", olMsg 
the macro finish but nothing is created, but when i write:
    Item.SaveAs "c:\myfile.msg", olMsg
outlooks says A program is trying to access e-mail addresses, Allow access for 1 Minutes. but the .msg its created :?

Comment: last question, how i can change:

    For Each oMailItem In oFolder.Items

for something like this:

    For i=1 to  oFolder.Items.count
oMailItem = oFolder.Items.item(i)

??